# Where-Object works locally but not remotely

Tags: powershell, powershell-remoting

I'm trying to learn PowerShell.
I wrote a small script to monitor my Exchange servers.
I can't understand why this line work on the local machine without problem

```
Get-WmiObject -Class win32_volume -Filter 'drivetype = 3' | Where-Object 'Label' -ne "System Reserved" | ft SystemName, DriveLetter, Label, @{LABEL='FreeSpaceGB'; EXPRESSION={"{0:N0}" -f ($_.freespace/1GB)}}
```

but if I put the same code into the invoke-command I get this error.

```
Invoke-Command -ComputerName $server -credential $c -ScriptBlock {
    Get-WmiObject -Class win32_volume -Filter 'drivetype = 3' | Where-Object 'Label' -ne "System Reserved" | ft SystemName, DriveLetter, Label, @{LABEL='FreeSpaceGB'; EXPRESSION={"{0:N0}" -f ($_.freespace/1GB)}}
    }
```

> Cannot bind argument to parameter 'FilterScript' because it is null.
>       + CategoryInfo          : InvalidData: (:) [Where-Object], ParameterBindingValidationException
>       + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ParameterArgumentValidationErrorNullNotAllowed,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.WhereObject
>   Command

I tried everything I can think of without luck.
I even check with gm and the Label do exist...
Any tip..?

Comment: I highly recommend the newer versions of PowerShell if you can. BIG if, though since some versions aren't compatible with certain versions of Exchange.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like the endpoint you're connecting to is PowerShell 2.0, which doesn't have the simplified Where-object syntax.

Try this where-object instead:

```
Where-Object {$_.Label -ne "System Reserved"}
```

Comment: Works. Thanks. I didn't think about the PS version discrepancy.